# Python tkinter GUI not showing properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some kind of problems with my GUI program, the scrollbar is just on the right of the last frame inside of bottom, I have tried a lot of things and nothing solve my problem, I just want to put the scrollbar on the bottom of all the frames.

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#spyder
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog



def curdir():
    cdir = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=finestra, initialdir="/home")  
    v.set(cdir)

#MAIN
finestra = Tk()
finestra.title("Creacio de fitxer comprimit")
f=Frame(finestra)

b=Button(f,text='Escollir directori treball',command=curdir)
b.pack(side=LEFT)

v=StringVar() 
v.set("/home")
e1=Entry(f,width=35,textvariable=v)

e1.pack(side=LEFT)

l1=Label(f,text="Fitxers a incorporar al fitxer tar:")
l1.pack(side=TOP,anchor=N,padx=90)
f.pack(side=TOP)

f1=Frame(finestra)
f1.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW)

l2=Label(f1,text="Llista:")
l2.pack(side=LEFT)

br=Button(f1,text='Reomplir')
br.pack(side=LEFT)
bo=Button(f1,text='Ocultar no seleccionats')
bo.pack(side=LEFT)
bos=Button(f1,text='Ocultar seleccionats')
bos.pack(side=LEFT)

Label(f1,text="\t\tCompresió").pack(side=LEFT)
rb1=Radiobutton(f1,text="cap").pack(side=LEFT)
rb2=Radiobutton(f1,text="gzip",value="gzip").pack(side=LEFT)
rb3=Radiobutton(f1,text="bzip2",value="bzip2").pack(side=LEFT)
rb4=Radiobutton(f1,text="xz",value="xz").pack(side=LEFT)

f2=Frame(finestra)
f2.pack(side=RIGHT,fill="both")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(f2)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(f2, bd=0, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)






mainloop( )
```

Comment: You are adding the scrollbar to f2.  Is that not where you want it?

Comment: Can you clarify a few things?  Firstly, when you say you want the scrollbar at the bottom of it's frame, in a horizontal orientation?  Secondly, are you saying that you want a scrollbar in each of your frames, or just f2?

Comment: i want the scrollbar at the bottom,i was adding frames because it was working,but when i arrive to that point,the frame is added at the right instead of at the bottom.

Comment: Do you want a _vertical_ scrollbar at the bottom? Or do you want it to be a horizontal scrollbar? I don't understand what you expect from a vertical scrollbar below all of the other widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally works changing frame f side option to TOP,seems that when you put something at TOP,the rest of the things will go down of this one,that was what i wasn't understanding,i let the final code maybe someone will have the same problem with tkinter frames position.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#spyder
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog



def curdir():
    cdir = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=finestra, initialdir="/home")  
    v.set(cdir)

#MAIN
finestra = Tk()
finestra.title("Creacio de fitxer comprimit")
f=Frame(finestra)
f.pack(side=TOP)

b=Button(f,text='Escollir directori treball',command=curdir)
b.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)

v=StringVar() 
v.set("/home")
e1=Entry(f,width=35,textvariable=v)

e1.pack(side=LEFT)

l1=Label(f,text="Fitxers a incorporar al fitxer tar:")
l1.pack(side=TOP,anchor=N,padx=90)


f1=Frame(finestra)
f1.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)

l2=Label(f1,text="Llista:")
l2.pack(side=LEFT)

br=Button(f1,text='Reomplir')
br.pack(side=LEFT)
bo=Button(f1,text='Ocultar no seleccionats')
bo.pack(side=LEFT)
bos=Button(f1,text='Ocultar seleccionats')
bos.pack(side=LEFT)

Label(f1,text="\t\tCompresió").pack(side=LEFT)
rb1=Radiobutton(f1,text="cap").pack(side=LEFT)
rb2=Radiobutton(f1,text="gzip",value="gzip").pack(side=LEFT)
rb3=Radiobutton(f1,text="bzip2",value="bzip2").pack(side=LEFT)
rb4=Radiobutton(f1,text="xz",value="xz").pack(side=LEFT)



f2=Frame(finestra)
f2.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)
f3=Frame(finestra)
f3.pack(side=LEFT)



Label(f3,text="Tots:").pack(side=TOP)
tots=Button(f3,text=">>>").pack(side=TOP)
Label(f3,text="Als seleccionats:").pack(side=TOP)
af=Button(f3,text="-->").pack(side=TOP)
qt=Button(f3,text="<--").pack(side=TOP)
Label(f3,text="Tots:").pack(side=TOP)
cap=Button(f3,text="<<<").pack(side=TOP)




scrollbar = Scrollbar(f2)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(f2, bd=0, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,width=55)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)




mainloop( )
```